# Python - 'unknown encoding: utf8mb4' when using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

Like the title says I am receiving the error 'unknown encoding: utf8mb4' when I try to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. I dont get this error if I use an INSERT IGNORE instead but then I lose the ability to upsert. This is what my code looks like:

```
MySQL version: 5.7.14-google-log
Python: 3.6.5
mysql-connector: 2.1.6


def mysqlLoader(vals, table, headers):
dbCon = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="-",
    user="-",
    passwd="-",
    database="-",
    charset='utf8mb4'
)

cursor = dbCon.cursor()
sql = generateSQL(table, headers, vals)
try:
    dbCon.autocommit = False
    cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
    cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
    cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")
    print('Executing SQL query...')
    cursor.executemany(sql, vals)
    print('Commiting to MySQL...')
    dbCon.commit()
    print("MySQL Updated Successfully! %s records inserted!" % cursor.rowcount)
except Exception as e:
    print("Could not commit entries: %s" % e)
    sendEmail('Data Loader Failed', 'Table: %s\r\nError: %s' % (table, e))


def generateSQL(table, headers, vals):
    valStrings = getSQLStrings(vals)
    updateVals = getUpdateString(headers)
    sql = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s' % (table, headers, valStrings, updateVals)
    print("Query created.")
    return sql

def getUpdateString(headers):
"""Outputs an ON DUPLICATE UPDATE string using the given headers."""
temp = ''
split = headers.split(', ')
for item in split:
    temp += '%s=VALUES(%s), ' % (item, item)
temp = temp[:(len(temp)-2)]
return temp
```

I can strip out emojis and other characters and revert back to utf8 but I would prefer to keep them for data integrity. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: It seems to be an issue with the executemany command. When I run inserts one at a time I dont throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious I was able to work around this by just using REPLACE instead of INSERT. Not a perfect solution but it fits my needs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug when it comes to multiple insert command in the old version of **mysql-connector** or even in the latest version of **mysql-connector-rf**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-1-7.html

The best solution is to go to **mysql-connector-python**, which is maintain the mysql team in Oracle.
https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/